# Telegram Bot API File Download Path Returns 404

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404, telegram, telegram-bot

I am currently working on a Telegram Bot project which requires me to download Images send by users to the bot.

I followed the API documentation which says to use the getFile call to access the file_path. The file should then be found using the path (https://api.telegram.org/file/bot/)

Everything works until I try to access the file using the address above. It always returns 404. However not a json containing the 404 message, but a black screen in the browser and 404 in the page response.

Maybe I am missing something.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and this was my error: i was using `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/<file_path>` instead of `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>`

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much, I don't know how I missed this.