# Telegram API file download path return 404

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

As a topicstarted [before me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669218/telegram-bot-api-file-download-path-returns-404), got issues with downloading a file via telegram bot.
Using python + pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot).

Sequence of actions:

1. Got update about file received and extracting file_id like: `BQACAgIAAxkBAANqXxfz1kGAatLmqZyhTndjmejo0LsAAq4HAAKCScFIxj2AovwylDMaBA`.
2. Using  `telebot.get_file_url` to get valid link to file.
   Got something like this:
   `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{HERE_IS_MY_BOT_TOKEN}/documents/file_22.csv`
3. Performing `telebot.download` using this URL is failed, cause of response:
   `[{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}]`.

Performing get request using Requests lib via same url return the same error.
But opening the same link using browser is working well and downloading the file.

Dear stackoverflow, need your help to figure out how to avoid this. ;3

Answer (score 0):

Actually, hardcoding "http" over "https" in download link resolved the problem for me.